# Error 500 after deploying CodeIgniter 3 project on nginx server

Tags: nginx, codeigniter-3, ubuntu-18.04

I am using Ubuntu 18.04 VPS and trying to deploy CodeIgniter project on nginx server. Unfortunately seems something is wrong in the nginx config file. Here is the file:

**nginx config:**

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    # Server Name
    server_name doamin.com;
    
    # Document Root
    root /var/www/html/domain.com;

    # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
    index index.php index.html index.htm;
    
    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
    }
    
    # pass PHP scripts to FastCGI server
    #
    location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;

        # With php-fpm:
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
    }


    error_page 404 /index.php;

    # deny access to hidden files such as .htaccess & .git
    location ~ /\. {
        deny all;
    }
    
}
```

**Directory Permissions**

> cd /var/www/

```
drwxr-xr-x  3 www-data www-data 4096 Feb 24 12:54 html/
```

> cd html/

```
drwxr-xr-x 6 root     root     4096 Feb 24 12:54 domain.com/
```

> cd domain.com/

```
drwxr-xr-x  8 root     root      4096 Feb 24 12:54 .git/
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root     root         0 Feb 24 12:54 .gitignore*
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root     root       241 Feb 24 12:54 .htaccess*
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root     root      7035 Feb 24 12:54 README.md*
drwxr-xr-x 14 root     root      4096 Feb 24 12:54 application/
drwxr-xr-x  8 root     root      4096 Feb 24 12:54 assets/
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root     root       593 Feb 24 12:54 composer.json*
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root     root     19306 Feb 24 12:54 database_schema.sql*
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root     root     10722 Feb 24 12:54 index.php*
drwxr-xr-x  8 root     root      4096 Feb 24 12:54 system/
```

Please help.

Comment: In nginx config instead of  `server_name doamin.com;` I am using `server_name domain.com;`.

Comment: Please run `nginx -t` command from command line and update your question with the result. + Check nginx error log file: In default located at **/var/log/nginx/** directory